# npm install error: cannot find module 'read-package-tree'

Tags: node.js, npm

executing the npm install command in windows 10 machine .

facing the below issue

```
C:\ >npm install
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'read-package-tree'
npm ERR! Require stack:
npm ERR! - C:\Users\dineshkumars2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\dineshkumars2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\dineshkumars2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dineshkumars2\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-31T02_21_08_042Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing `read-package-tree` using npm command as,

`npm i read-package-tree`

In case same error showing for executing the above command, Please copy the folder from another machine and paste it into the path that where `node_modules` are in.

Ex:

```
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules
```

then run the below command `npm i read-package-tree` it will resolve the issue, now we can able to run the command 'npm install'

Comment: executing these command facing the same issue again, and unable to uninstall npm also. can i delete the folder and reinstall again is it possible ? C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\

Comment: Yes, try to delete the folder and reinstall again

Comment: thanks , it working for me i copied from another machine read-package-tree and paste into the below path C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules

Comment: So, I think it is a problem in installing the package correctly.